# problema al eliminar base datos postgresql dentro de php

Tags: php, postgresql

siempre me da:

> no borrada la base datos: bdsociedad. Query falled: ERROR: no se puede
>   eliminar la base de datos activa

???

```
$query="SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = current_database() and pid <> pg_backend_pid()";
$retval0=pg_query($query);// or die ('Query falled: '.pg_last_error());
if (!$retval0) echo 'no activa base datos';
$query="DROP DATABASE bdsociedad";
$retval=pg_query($query);// or die ('Query falled: '.pg_last_error());
if ($retval!=FALSE){
    echo '<font style="Tahoma" color="#0000ff" size= 2>';
    echo '<br>borrada la base datos: bdsociedad<br><br>';
    }
else{
    echo '<font style="Tahoma" color="#ff0000" size= 2>';
    echo '<br>no borrada la base datos: bdsociedad. Query falled: '.pg_last_error().'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer, describe, mas el problema que tienes y los errores que te salen.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = current_database() and pid <> pg_backend_pid()"; $retval0=pg_query($query);// or die ('Query falled: '.pg_last_error()); 
if (!$retval0) echo 'no activa base datos'; 
$query="DROP DATABASE bdsociedad"; 
$retval=pg_query($query);// or die ('Query falled: '.pg_last_error());
if ($retval!=FALSE){
    echo '<font style="Tahoma" color="#0000ff" size= 2>';
    echo '<br>borrada la base datos: bdsociedad<br><br>';
    }
else{
    echo '<font style="Tahoma" color="#ff0000" size= 2>';
    echo '<br>no borrada la base datos: bdsociedad. Query falled: '.pg_last_error().'<br>';
    }
```

no se editó bien.

Comment: esto es una respuesta? por que si no lo es no va en esta zona y va en tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Jesus, por favor agrega una explicación del código, te sugiero revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Cierra todas las conexiones que tengas activa o reinicia el postgreslq, tambien podrias user el comando

```
systemctl stop postgres
```